# Loading a Joomla 2.5 module into another module

Tags: joomla, module, position, joomla2.5, loadmodule

I've seen the question [Loading a module in another module in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770303/loading-a-module-in-another-module-in-joomla), but that was about Joomla 1.5

I have exactly the same question about Joomla 2.5

Is there an official way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a "Custom HTML" module the standard `{loadposition myPosition}` or `{loadmodule myModuleTypesName}` work as expected.

Did you mean something else?

I've updated the [wiki article](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F) with the following information as well.

#### loadmodule

An alternative to "{loadposition xx}" is the "{loadmodule yyy}" variation which is handled by the same plugin.
In this case the plugin looks for the first module that who's type matches the string 'yyy'. So, you could load a "mod_login" module by placing {loadmodule login} in your text.

#### Modules within Modules

It is possible in Joomla! 2.5+ (possibly earlier) to include a module within a "Custom HTML" module as they are processed by content plugins in the same way as articles.
You should remember when doing this that you may experience formatting issues as the "chrome" of the "Custom HTML" module will surround the "chrome" of the included module potential having undesirable effects of the formatting or layout.

Comment: My God, where had they said that it also works in modules?! I thought it only works in articles! Thank you very much. I will test it and will ask you if it didn't work.

Comment: Yes `{loadposition myPosition}` worked, but I haven't heard anything about `{loadMODULE myModuleTypesName}`. (Ref: http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F ). Where is the document about loadMODULE ? Thank you

Comment: For others, as it's stated in the wiki page, do NOT forget to enable "Prepare content" of the custom HTML module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension, hope this may help you

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere

Answer (score 0):

In Custom HTML module `Options Tab` I set `Prepare Content` to 'yes' that allowes load other modules and positions.

**Joomla 2.5**

[image]

**Joomla 3**

[image]